# apt-get update fails on 17.04

Tags: apt, 17.04, docker

Running this very simple Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:17.04

RUN apt-get update
```

fails with these errors:

```
W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This looks like a Ubuntu problem rather than a Docker problem.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Changing to 16.04 solved the problem.  What's the problem with 17.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is a short-term release; with a supported life of 9 months only. Released in 2017.April (hence 17.04) it's 9 months ended early 2018; and you were supposed to upgrade to 17.10 (the 2017.October release; itself now EOL too).  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS & 18.04 LTS are long-term-support releases with a supported life of 5 years. If you want a longer life than 9 months, stick to LTS releases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: _This looks like a Ubuntu problem rather than a Docker problem._ -- I respectfully disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.04, Released in 2017.April (hence 17.04) is a short-term or standard Ubuntu release; with a supported life of 9 months only.

Ubuntu 17.04 users were prompted to upgrade to 17.10 (the 2017.October release), however it too is now EOL (but users were prompted to upgrade to 18.04 LTS).

Post a release reaching EOL; its repos are moved from `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` which occurred long ago with 17.04; but hasn't yet occurred with 17.10 (*it only very recently reached its EOL; in a few weeks its repositories will be moved too*)

If you want/need a longer life, use long-term-support releases, such as Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (2014.April), 16.04 LTS (2016.April) & 18.04 LTS (2018.April) with a supported life of 5 years each.

Comment: If you were hoping all April releases are LTS; sorry - only even years are; hence 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS & 18.04 LTS, with the next expected in 2020.April (20.04 LTS)